# Erro ao mudar de Activity

Tags: java, android

Boa noite, tenho um app com duas Activity que carrega dados externos, e to tendo problema para mudar de Activity antes dela te carregado todos os dados.Quando chamo a Activity Categoria, ele carrega dados externos, mas se chamar a Activity produtos antes da Activity Categoria carregar todos os dados eu tenho esse erro :

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: com.example.soares.comprassupermecado, PID: 25322
                  android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { flg=0x14000000 launchParam=MultiScreenLaunchParams { mDisplayId=0 mBaseDisplayId=0 mFlags=0 } }
                      at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1844)
                      at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1531)
                      at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4403)
                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:754)
                      at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4362)
                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:741)
                      at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4686)
                      at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4654)
                      at com.example.soares.comprassupermecado.TelaPrincipal.onNavigationItemSelected(TelaPrincipal.java:166)
                      at android.support.design.widget.NavigationView$1.onMenuItemSelected(NavigationView.java:170)
                      at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuBuilder.dispatchMenuItemSelected(MenuBuilder.java:840)
                      at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java:158)
                      at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:991)
                      at android.support.design.internal.NavigationMenuPresenter$1.onClick(NavigationMenuPresenter.java:352)
                      at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6261)
                      at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:23752)
                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6776)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1496)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1386)
```

Minha Activity Principal(navigation drawer )

```
package com.example.soares.comprassupermecado;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.soares.comprassupermecado.Fragments.Fragment_Categorias;
import com.example.soares.comprassupermecado.Fragments.Fragment_Produtos;
import com.example.soares.comprassupermecado.Fragments.Fragment_lista;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

import de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView;

public class TelaPrincipal extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    public static final String StatusLoginAuto = "StatusLoginAuto";

    String UrlFoto = "";
    String NomeUser = "";
    String fragmentAction = "";
    Context context;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_tela_principal);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

        View hView =  navigationView.getHeaderView(0);

        SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(StatusLoginAuto, 0);
        UrlFoto = settings.getString("fotouser","");
        NomeUser = settings.getString("nomeuser","");

        TextView UserLogado = (TextView)hView.findViewById(R.id.EditUserLogado);
        TextView BemVindo = (TextView)hView.findViewById(R.id.EditBemVindo);

        String LinkFotoUSer = "http://192.168.0.120/profile/" + UrlFoto;

        CircleImageView imagem_profile = (CircleImageView)hView.findViewById(R.id.ImageProfile);

        BemVindo.setText("Olá,");
        UserLogado.setText(NomeUser);
        Picasso.get().load(LinkFotoUSer).into(imagem_profile);

        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Lista de Compras");
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new Fragment_lista())
                .commit();
        fragmentAction = "2";
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_os, menu);
        MenuItem shareItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_back);

        if (fragmentAction.equals("1")) {
            shareItem.setVisible(false);
        }
        if (fragmentAction.equals("2")) {
            shareItem.setVisible(true);
        }
        if (fragmentAction.equals("3")) {
            shareItem.setVisible(false);
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
                finishAffinity();
            }
        }
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {


        switch (item.getItemId()) {

            case R.id.action_back:

                if (getSupportFragmentManager().getFragments() != null && getSupportFragmentManager().getFragments().size() > 0) {
                    for (int i = 0; i  0) {
            for (int i = 0; i 

Activity Categoria


package com.example.soares.comprassupermecado.Fragments;


import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.soares.comprassupermecado.ItemFragments.ItemCategorias;
import com.example.soares.comprassupermecado.ListAdapter.ListAdapterCategorias;
import com.example.soares.comprassupermecado.NewCategoria;
import com.example.soares.comprassupermecado.R;
import com.example.soares.comprassupermecado.ViewCategoria;
import com.example.soares.comprassupermecado.WebService.ConexaoDB;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Fragment_Categorias extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {

    private String url = "";
    private String parametros ="";
    public static final String StatusLoginAuto = "StatusLoginAuto";
    private ListView listCategoria;
    private ProgressBar progressBar;
    private TextView textresultbusca;
    private ImageView BtnNovaCategoria;
    private int i;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private View view;

    ArrayList listaCategoria = new ArrayList();

    String StatusJson = "";
    String NomeCategoria = "";
    String IdCategoria = "";
    String QuantCategoria = "";
    String ObsCategoria = "";

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        if (view == null) {

            SharedPreferences settings = this.getActivity().getSharedPreferences(StatusLoginAuto, 0);
            String Chave = settings.getString("chaveusuario","");

            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fragment__categorias,null);
            listCategoria = (ListView)view.findViewById(R.id.listCategorias);

            final Handler handler = new Handler();
            boolean b = handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    ListAdapterCategorias adapterCategorias = new ListAdapterCategorias(getContext(), listaCategoria);

                    listCategoria.setAdapter(adapterCategorias);
                    progressBar = (ProgressBar) view.findViewById(R.id.HeaderProgressCategoria);
                    textresultbusca = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.ResultBuscaCategoria);
                    BtnNovaCategoria = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.BtnNovaCategoria);

                    progressBar.setVisibility(view.GONE);
                    BtnNovaCategoria.setVisibility(view.VISIBLE);

                    if (StatusJson.equals("1")) {

                        textresultbusca.setVisibility(view.VISIBLE);
                    }

                }
            }, 5000);

            listCategoria.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView adapterView, View view, int position, long id) {

                    TextView TextIDCategoria   = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.TextID);
                    TextView TextNomeCategoria = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.TextNomeCategoria);
                    TextView TextObsCategoria  = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.TextObs);
                    TextView TextQuantProdutos = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.NumerosQuantProdutos);


                    String IDCategoria = TextIDCategoria.getText().toString();
                    String NomeCategoria = TextNomeCategoria.getText().toString();
                    String ObsCategoria = TextObsCategoria.getText().toString();
                    String QuantCategoria = TextQuantProdutos.getText().toString();

                    Bundle extras = new Bundle();
                    extras.putString("idcategoria",IDCategoria);
                    extras.putString("nomecategoria",NomeCategoria);
                    extras.putString("obscategoria",ObsCategoria);
                    extras.putString("quantcategoria",QuantCategoria);


                    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), ViewCategoria.class);
                    intent.putExtras(extras);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            });
        }
        return view;
    }


    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        listaCategoria.clear();
        listCategoria = (ListView)view.findViewById(R.id.listCategorias);
        progressBar = (ProgressBar) view.findViewById(R.id.HeaderProgressCategoria);
        textresultbusca = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.ResultBuscaCategoria);
        BtnNovaCategoria = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.BtnNovaCategoria);

        listCategoria.setAdapter(null);

        progressBar.setVisibility(view.VISIBLE);
        BtnNovaCategoria.setVisibility(view.GONE);
        textresultbusca.setVisibility(view.GONE);

        SharedPreferences settings = this.getActivity().getSharedPreferences(StatusLoginAuto, 0);
        String Chave = settings.getString("chaveusuario","");

        url = "http://192.168.0.120/compras/categorias.php?status=listview&chave=" + Chave;
        new SolicitarDados().execute(url);

        final Handler handler = new Handler();
        boolean b = handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                ListAdapterCategorias adapterCategorias = new ListAdapterCategorias(getContext(), listaCategoria);

                listCategoria.setAdapter(adapterCategorias);
                progressBar.setVisibility(view.GONE);
                BtnNovaCategoria.setVisibility(view.VISIBLE);

                if (StatusJson.equals("1")) {

                    textresultbusca.setVisibility(view.VISIBLE);
                }

            }
        }, 5000);
        super.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        BtnNovaCategoria = (ImageView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.BtnNovaCategoria);
        BtnNovaCategoria.setOnClickListener((View.OnClickListener) this);
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(final View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.BtnNovaCategoria:
                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), NewCategoria.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                break;
        }
    }

    private class  SolicitarDados extends AsyncTask {

        View view;


        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
            return ConexaoDB.postDados(urls[0], parametros);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {


            if(result != null) {
                try {
                    JSONArray jsonarray = new JSONArray(result);
                    for (i = 0; i 

Activity Produto


package com.example.soares.comprassupermecado.Fragments;


import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;
import com.example.soares.comprassupermecado.ItemFragments.ItemProdutos;
import com.example.soares.comprassupermecado.ListAdapter.ListAdapterProdutos;
import com.example.soares.comprassupermecado.NewCategoria;
import com.example.soares.comprassupermecado.NewProduto;
import com.example.soares.comprassupermecado.R;
import com.example.soares.comprassupermecado.ViewProduto;
import com.example.soares.comprassupermecado.WebService.ConexaoDB;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Fragment_Produtos extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener  {

    private String url ="";
    private String parametros ="";

    private ListView listProdutos;
    private ProgressBar progressBar;
    private TextView textresultbusca;
    private ImageView BtnNovoProduto;
    private int i;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private View view;
    public static final String StatusLoginAuto = "StatusLoginAuto";

    ArrayList listaProdutos = new ArrayList();

    String StatusJson = "";
    String NomeProduto = "";
    String IdProduto = "";
    String ObsProduto = "";
    String CategoriaProduto = "";
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        if (view == null) {

            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fragment__produtos,null);
            listProdutos = (ListView)view.findViewById(R.id.listProduto);

            final Handler handler = new Handler();
            boolean b = handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    ListAdapterProdutos adapterProdutos = new ListAdapterProdutos(getContext(), listaProdutos);

                    listProdutos.setAdapter(adapterProdutos);
                    progressBar = (ProgressBar) view.findViewById(R.id.HeaderProgressProduto);
                    textresultbusca = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.ResultBuscaProduto);
                    BtnNovoProduto = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.BtnNovoProduto);

                    progressBar.setVisibility(view.GONE);
                    BtnNovoProduto.setVisibility(view.VISIBLE);

                    if (StatusJson.equals("1")) {

                        textresultbusca.setVisibility(view.VISIBLE);
                    }

                }
            }, 5000);

            listProdutos.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView adapterView, View view, int position, long id) {

                    TextView TextIDProduto   = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.TextIDProduto);
                    TextView TextNomeProduto = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.TextNomeProduto);
                    TextView TextObsProduto  = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.TextObsProduto);
                    TextView TextCategoriaProduto = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.TextNomeProduto);

                    String IDProduto = TextIDProduto.getText().toString();
                    String NomeProduto = TextNomeProduto.getText().toString();
                    String ObsProduto = TextObsProduto.getText().toString();
                    String CategoriaProduto = TextCategoriaProduto.getText().toString();

                    Bundle extras = new Bundle();
                    extras.putString("idproduto",IDProduto);
                    extras.putString("nomeproduto",NomeProduto);
                    extras.putString("obsproduto",ObsProduto);
                    extras.putString("categoriaproduto",CategoriaProduto);


                    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), ViewProduto.class);
                    intent.putExtras(extras);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            });
        }
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        listaProdutos.clear();
        listProdutos = (ListView)view.findViewById(R.id.listProduto);
        progressBar = (ProgressBar) view.findViewById(R.id.HeaderProgressProduto);
        textresultbusca = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.ResultBuscaProduto);
        BtnNovoProduto = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.BtnNovoProduto);

        listProdutos.setAdapter(null);

        progressBar.setVisibility(view.VISIBLE);
        BtnNovoProduto.setVisibility(view.GONE);
        textresultbusca.setVisibility(view.GONE);

        SharedPreferences settings = this.getActivity().getSharedPreferences(StatusLoginAuto, 0);
        String Chave = settings.getString("chaveusuario","");

        url = "http://192.168.0.120/compras/produtos.php?status=listview&chave=" + Chave;

        new SolicitarDados().execute(url);

        final Handler handler = new Handler();
        boolean b = handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                ListAdapterProdutos adapterProdutos = new ListAdapterProdutos(getContext(), listaProdutos);

                listProdutos.setAdapter(adapterProdutos);
                progressBar = (ProgressBar) view.findViewById(R.id.HeaderProgressProduto);
                textresultbusca = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.ResultBuscaProduto);
                BtnNovoProduto = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.BtnNovoProduto);

                progressBar.setVisibility(view.GONE);
                BtnNovoProduto.setVisibility(view.VISIBLE);

                if (StatusJson.equals("1")) {

                    textresultbusca.setVisibility(view.VISIBLE);
                }

            }
        }, 5000);
        super.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        BtnNovoProduto = (ImageView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.BtnNovoProduto);
        BtnNovoProduto.setOnClickListener((View.OnClickListener) this);
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(final View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.BtnNovoProduto:
                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), NewProduto.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                break;
        }
    }

    private class  SolicitarDados extends AsyncTask {

        View view;


        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
            return ConexaoDB.postDados(urls[0], parametros);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {


            if(result != null) {
                try {
                    JSONArray jsonarray = new JSONArray(result);
                    for (i = 0; i 

Manifest
```

Acontece a mesma coisa mudando a ordem das Activitys. Podem me Ajudar  ?

Comment: Poste o seu código em que uma _Activity_ chama a outra e poste seu `manifest.xml` também.

Comment: atualizei a pergunta com os codigos

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consegui resolver, o erro acontecer pq quando termina de carregar os dados e vai setar o ArrayAdapter, a Activity não ta mais aberta, então resolvi colocando uma verificar do status da Activity antes de setar os dados.